# Run script for each div with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I'm running ISOTOPE. So I have to set the DIV's height and width through jQuery. It's a photographer's portfolio, so I have thousand of photos with different sizes.

HTML

```
<div class="element  metal cesco1 " data-symbol="Hg" data-category="transition">
<span>
<a class="fancybox" href="fotos/full/full01.png" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
<img src="fotos/thumbs/thumb01.png"/>
</a>
</span>
</div>

<div class="element  metal cesco1 " data-symbol="Hg" data-category="transition">
<span>
<a class="fancybox" href="fotos/full/full03.png" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
<img src="fotos/thumbs/thumb03.png"/>
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 0;
$('.cesco1 img').each(function() {
width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
alert(width);
});
$('.cesco1').css('width', width + 0);
</script>
```

I'm using the same JavaScript for height as well. 
The first thumb width is 300px and the second is 200px.
So I get the a 500px width div.it adds up. 
I would like to set the width for each DIV at the time.
I'm a newbie, sorry if it's dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.closest()` method to access the `DIV` that contains the image.

```
$('.cesco1 img').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    alert(width);
    $(this).closest('.cesco1').css('width', width);
});
```

If the image is always an immediate child of the DIV, you can use the more efficient selector `.cesco1 > img` and `.parent()` instead of `.closest('.cesco1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.cesco1').each(function() {
          var width = 0;
          $(this).children('img').each(function(){ 
              width += $(this).outerWidth( true );  // reset the width
          });
          $(this).css('width', width);
        });
    });
</script>
```